# how to represent rotation around 3D axis as a rotation around an fixed axis and what is the angle of the rotation

Tags: 3d, rotation

I want to know where is the equation for 3D rotation come from?(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). and if I want to rotate a point first around x axis for thetax degree, then rotate around y axis for thetay degree, at last rotate around z axis for thetaz degree, I want to ask: how to define the ux, uy, and uz in the above equation?

and how to compute the theta in the equation?

thanks for reading

Comment: What are you exactly talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Trigonometry, the 2x2 matrix is just 2 two dimensional vectors. For higher dimensions you need a 3x3 or a affine 4x4 matrix. See image:

[image: 2d rotation matrix]

For a combination of these just matrix multiply the matrices together in the order or reverse order you need them (order depends on you have column or row vectors). In this particular case they are rowmajor matrices and thus multplication is in reverse order.